# Populate a sharer link for facebook

Tags: facebook

Im using this URL to share my website without having to add any facebook code:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://yahoo.com

And I was wondering, is there any way to populate the description field, like another URL parameter?

EDIT: Seems like sharer its deprecated in favour of the like button, but i dont want to use the ugly look of the like button. is there a way to replace it? Im trying to achieve an effect like this in twitter:

```
<a href='http://twitter.com/home?status=My_message' <img src='mytwittericon.png' /></a>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook "sharer" has been deprecated and is no longer supported as it states [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

Comment: But I want to use a custom image, not the ugly like button. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. You can play a bit with how the button looks like (have faces or not, add the *Send* button as well, etc) but you have to use their design. What's good about it is that users are used to see this button, they won't miss it or be afraid to click it, so even if you think it "craps your style", in reality it will probably cause your users to like/share more.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find Sharer more useful than Like button.

Try this code:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=URL to share &p[title]=Title&p[images][0]=image link&p[summary]=My website summary"><img src="http://yourdefaultsharebutton.png"></a>
```

Or just set proper OG tags.